# ElasticLoadBalancingV2 describe_load_balancers not returning results in ruby aws sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the V2 version of the ElasticLoadBalancing API because the V1 version does not return an ARN.  I've boiled down my issue in the code fragment below:

```
client = Aws::ElasticLoadBalancing::Client.new(region: "us-east-1")
resp = client.describe_load_balancers
puts("V1: Number of load balancers returned: #{resp.load_balancer_descriptions.length}")
```

Output: 9

```
client = Aws::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Client.new(region: "us-east-1")
resp = client.describe_load_balancers
puts("V2: Number of load balancers returned: #{resp.load_balancers.length}")
```

Output: 0

Indeed, the account this is going against does have 9 load balancers.

I am using aws-sdk-core-2.10.90.

### Update

Thanks to John for answering.  I did not find this mentioned in the [ruby sdk documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws.html), but is mentioned on their [main web service documentation page](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elastic-load-balancing/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V1 API is for the Classic Load Balancers. V2 is for Application and Network Load Balancers.